# Self sizing cells for nested table and collection Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to build a table view, one of the cells in this TableView is a tabs widget. 
so I'm creating this tab widget as a CollectionView. the cells of the collectionView have different subViews and each cell has it's own size.

what I'm trying to achieve is Self-sizing cells in the collectionView, but it is not working.

I'll provide you with the way I used so I can get your help.

```
//MARK: TableView
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsTabs", for: indexPath) as! DetailsTabs /*this cell has 2 collectionViews. The first collectionView is the tabs and the second collectionView is the content that should be diplayed. I gave the first collectionView a fixed height, trailing leading and top. the second collectionView has trailing, leading bottom, and top to the first collectionView*/
        cell.postDetail = postDetail
        cell.widgets = self.Template
        cell.parentController = self
        cell.Shownavigationbar = self.Shownavigationbar

        return cell
}

//MARK: DetailsTabs Class

 override func awakeFromNib() {
//code to setUp the collectionViews

//pagesLayout is the UICollectionViewFlowLayout for the second collectionView
       pagesLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1)
        }

//MARK: IN collectionView Cells I added this function:
 override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()

        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame

        return layoutAttributes
    }
```

note: the content of the collectionView cells might be webView or tableview.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

you should use **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** in *estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath*

hope this is working fine for you...!

Comment: did not work. but i have already added these 2 lines in `viewDidLoad`.

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300`

Comment: can you edit your answer and share your screenShot how your design look like